# REST SDK - could not find OpenSSL

Tags: cmake, onedrive

I am trying to use the `REST SDK` to make a OneDrive command line app. The only issue is I cannot install it.

Here is the [link](https://casablanca.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Setup%20and%20Build%20on%20OSX&referringTitle=Documentation) to the instructions I used (for Mac).

I got up to the cmake installation then I got an error. Here is my terminal output.

```
Folder=build.release;-time=16:07:22: cmake ../Release -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
-- Boost version: 1.57.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   random
--   chrono
--   system
--   thread
--   locale
--   regex
--   filesystem
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.1.3/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:138 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
  system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR: Found unsuitable version "0.9.8zc", but
  required is at least "1.0.0" (found
  /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2/lib/libssl.dylib;/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2/lib/libcrypto.dylib)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.1.3/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:372 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.1.3/share/cmake/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:318 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:85 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/{User}/programing/OneDrive/casablanca-219daed12e45618aeffc94b73b83af55c3dca7aa/build.release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
Folder=build.release;-time=16:07:41:
```

I have installed OpenSSL via brew like it said (even did `brew link --force openssl`).
I also chose to do the direct download from [here](https://casablanca.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) since I could not get `git clone` to work.

How would I change the path like it says? OpenSSL is installed in is `/usr/bin/openssl`

**Note**

`Folder=build.release;-time=16:07:22:` is my custom bash prompt and **not** part of the log.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.

To fix it I just used this command: `cmake ../Release -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl`.

Found the answer here: http://www.cmake.org/Bug/bug_relationship_graph.php?bug_id=15075.

Answer (score 0):

Latest stable version(3.0.2) have this bug (https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=784443) but if You try newer unstable version (I tried 3.2.3) it works fine!